# Can I use python float with precision of (float32)?

Tags: serialization, tensorflow, floating-point, precision, msgpack

Can I use python float with precision of (float32) ?
Because it will be serialized from primitive python.float(32) and will be deserialized to primitive java.float.
Any libraries are not considered. ex) numpy.float32

Comment: Have you tried it? You will have much better chances of getting an answer if you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Python floats are 64-bit (`double` in C/Java). However you can serialize/deserialize these to 32-bit floats (`float` in C/Java) using the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module with the `"f"` format:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("f", 0.1)
'\xcd\xcc\xcc='
```